# ACL on the directory itself

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I have a directory

```
..../test
```

With the follow ACL permissions.

```
$ getfacl test
# file: test
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:usl:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:usl:rw-
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

It works great with user usl beeing able to write inside the directory, but the user do not have write permission on the directory itself?

```
$ rmdir test
rmdir: failed to remove `test': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing a directory requires write permission in the parent of that directory also, since that directory needs to be updated.